# How Do I Generate Sybase BCP Fmt file?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a huge database which I want to dump out using BCP and then load it up elsewhere. I have done quite a bit of research on the Sybase version of BCP (being more familiar with the MSSQL one) and I see how to USE an Import file but I can't figure out for the life of me how to create one.

I am currently making my Sybase bcp out files of data like this:

```
bcp mytester.dbo.XTABLE out XTABLE.bcp -U sa -P mypass -T -n
```

and trying to import them back in like this:

```
bcp mytester.dbo.XTABLE in XTABLE.bcp  -E -n -S Sybase_157 -U sa -P SyAdmin
```

Right now, the IN part gives me an error about IDENTITY_INSERT regardless of if the table has an identity or not:

> Server Message: Sybase157 - Msg 7756, Level 16, State 1: Cannot use
>   'SET IDENTITY_INSERT' for table 'mytester.dbo.XTABLE' because the
>   table does not have the identity property.

I have often used the great info on this page for help, but this is the first time i've put in a question, so i humbly request any guidance you all can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BCP in, the `-E` flag tells bcp to take identity column values from the input file.  I would try running it without that flag.  fmt files in Sybase are a bit finicky, and I would try to avoid if possible.  So as long as your schemas are the same between your systems the following command should work:

```
bcp mytester.dbo.XTABLE in XTABLE.bcp -n -S Sybase_157 -U sa -P SyAdmin
```

Also, the `-T` flag on your bcp out seems odd.  I know SQLServer -T is a security setting, but in Sybase it indicates the max size of a text or image column, and is followed by a number..e.g `-T 32000` (would be 32Kbytes)

But to answer the question in your title, if you run **bcp** out interactively (without specifying `-c`,`-n`, or `-f`) it will step through each column, prompting for information.  At the end it will ask if you want to create a format file, and allow you to specify the name of the file.

For reference, here is the syntax and available flags:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/X14951.htm

And the chapter in the Utility Guide:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/BABGCCIC.htm

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, I also had to run :   sp_dboption mytester,'select into/bulkcopy',true  in order to allow bcp to insert, but after that, it was golden! Tahank you so much Michael. I'd do a +1 on your comment but I'm new and it wont let me :)