# How can I specifie column order while Bulk Copying (BCP) Out the tables from SYBASE_IQ.

Tags: sql, sybase, bcp, sap-iq

Below is the code I am using in the batch script to BCP process.

call bcp.exe DBName.tablename  out FILENAME.csv -e FILENAMEerr.txt -c  -t"|" -U USER DETAILS -P PASSWORD -S Servicename -r"\n"

Comment: consider using a format file to designate the order of the columns in the output file; alternatively, create a view (with the columns listed in the desired order) and then `bc`p out from the view

Comment: I don't have access to the Sybase_IQ DB. only select access I have. Is there any other way I could specify while BCP out.

Comment: see if you can get access to create a view in the temp db/space area;  the other option would be to use a format file

Comment: I am actually new to this can you tell me What's the format file process.

Comment: a search for `bcp format file` should bring up quite a bit (eg, - [how do I generate a bcp format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526703/how-do-i-generate-sybase-bcp-fmt-file))